# ! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'

Tags: latex

I've encountered a problem trying to compile a LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{mycaption}
\end{table}
...
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile it, this error message is displayed:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You must be doing something else, as [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) provides this and there's no problem with your code. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem.